# Efficient way to plot oscilloscope .trc files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I found this script to read .trc files with python and it works fine:

https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc

Only problem is that to restructure and plot the file seems to be very slow. I can plot a .trc file of 200KB but when I try to plot one of 200MB my machine just freezes. These files have many millions of values. To be fair, my machine is a 6 year old laptop which runs very slowly.

I wonder if one of you guys know a more efficient script to handle .trc files than that provided above.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import readTrc

datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00000.trc')

srx, sry = pd.Series(datX), pd.Series(datY)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

df.plot(grid = 1)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Artur

Comment: If it takes too long too load, buy a new computer. If it just takes too long to plot simply downsample your signal.

Comment: You really need to separate your problem into two (or maybe three) parts. (1) Loading the data; see how long it takes to load the data, e.g. with IPython's `%timeit`. (2) aggregating data; see how long the pandas reshaping takes. (3) Plotting the data; this is probably the step where it fails, because plotting millions of points may be slow. Then decide what you want to do; if (1) and (2) are acceptable, try to think if it makes sense to plot that many data at all (having in mind that a computer screen cannot show more than 2000 pixels in width.)

Comment: Will do, thank you :-)